# Change duration of splash screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2010, splash-screen

I recently added a splash screen to my WPF app.My app loads fast so the screen is only on for milliseconds.How would i lengthen the time my splash screen stays up.I would like it to be two seconds.

Comment: I would hate using an app that artifically makes itself feel slower just to show something I'm not interested anyway (i.e. a splash screen).

Comment: @UweKeim Any Ideas to make it longer

Comment: How about getting rid of the splash screen altogether?

Comment: @UweKeim Unfortunately it is a must in my app.I cant sway from my guidelines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you trigger the splash screen to show in the Application.Startup Event you will have full control over it. (be sure to call .Show() with false)

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
   SplashScreen screen = new SplashScreen("splashScreen.png");
   screen.Show(false);
}
```

Then you can call screen.Close() when you would like the splash screen to close.

Comment: would i be putting this in app.xaml.cs?

Comment: correct. you can find a example of how to do this here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx (you also need to attach the event in the xaml)

Answer (score 5):

You can also call 
*System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()* before the *InitializeComponent* in the main window. this works.

something like that:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        InitializeComponent();}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way and using the API is

```
  SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("splashscreen.jpg");
  splash.Show(false);
  splash.Close(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2));
  InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: `Close(TimeSpan)` does a Close with the specified TimeSpan as **fadeout** time. OP wants to increase the duration of the splash, not of its fadeout.